# Enabling multitouch, right-click, screen-keyboard, pitch-zoom, etc. on tablet

Tags: 11.10, tablet, touchscreen, ubuntu-touch

I want to install Ubuntu 11.10 on my Tablet (MSI WindPad 110W, currently running windows 8), but the touch-controls are not as it should be:

- Multitouch doesn't work. Which software/settings do I need?
- Right click doesn't work. (Holding the finger on the screen)
- The performance of the screen keyboard is very bad.
- Scrolling of websites etc. doesn't work
- pitch-to-zoom doesn't work

Need help please!

Answer (score 1):

Execute `lsusb` commmand, find your touchscreen ID in the output (looks like `04e7:0022`) and check if it's present in this list of supported multitouch devices:

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html

If it's not you can try enabling it and reporting compatibility here:

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-howto.html

Comment: It would be really really nice if anybody could adapt the ENAC tutorials for the specific case of Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried enhancing the answer. What do you think?